# Получить ответ в виде данных js

Tags: javascript, fetch, parse

Делаю запрос на сервер методом fetch

```
fetch(`https://example.com`,
            {mode: 'no-cors'})
            .then(res => console.log(res))
```

В консоли выводит вот это:
[image]

Однако во вкладке Сети я вижу, что в качестве ответа пришли данные, с которыми я хочу работать. Как мне их достать?
[image]

Comment: "no-cors" - без этого не работает?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```js
fetch(`https://example.com`,
            {mode: 'no-cors'})
            .then(res => console.log(res.json()))
```

Comment: Сервер возвращает не json, а просто файл

Comment: @ДаниилЛомин res.blob()
Но у вас, как я понял, запрос на финам, а на финаме возвращает не файл, а текст. Так что res.text()

Comment: если я использую метод ```.text()``` то получается это _Promise {<fulfilled>: ''}_

Comment: Может быть как нибудь сохранить все в файл, а потом считать с него?

Comment: если я добавляю дополнительный then то он выводит пустую строку, будто в ответе ничего нет